# How to delete a Django model referenced by unmanaged view model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models, one a vanilla Django model, another an unmanaged model wrapping a view.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myview'
```

Everything works well, unless I try to delete a row from A, which gives me an error like:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: cannot delete from view "myview"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule or an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger.
```

Apparently, Django is assuming the unmanaged model is a table, and is therefore trying to delete the dependent rows, and since it's a readonly view, my PostgreSQL backend is throwing this error.

Is there any way around this?

I found [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10829) outlining the issue, but none of the stopgap hacks seem to work for me, and the bug itself was marked a duplicate of another slightly different yet unresolved bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried [`on_delete=models.SET_NULL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) as a workaround?

Comment: It's a readonly view, so I can't set anything to null, but models.DO_NOTHING worked. Thanks.